# How to check presence of element after unmarshalling in JAXB?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jaxb, unmarshalling

Can someone help me understand how to check the presence of an element after unmarshalling XML into an Object? The element has no attributes and is also self closing! I did find few questions related to this, but it doesn't have any specific answer to it.

```
<Success /> //This is the self closing tag.

public class ParentClass {

    @XmlElement
    private Success success;

    public static class Success {

    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried unmarshalling with `<Success/>` and without? See any difference?

Comment: Thanks, see, I'm still picking up with JAXB. Can you confirm if the piece of Class I have written is good enough? AM I missing something? I will try what you're saying?

Comment: I think this could work. `success` will be either `null` if no `<Success/>` element present or an instance of it otherwise. But please test and report. You can answer your own question.

Comment: In both the circumstances, the Success elements shows null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is resolved now. I removed xmlns attribute from the XML message. Now if the success attribute is present, I get it in the object otherwise, it shows up null.